# Footnotes on the current page with mdframed

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

Is there a way to force a footnote to be on the current page when I use a multi-page `mdframed` box ?

With this box, I must use the pair `\footnotetext`/`\footnotemark`.

Currently, I used this next code. But, the 3 footnotes are on the last page of the box. How I can put each footnote on the current page where they are called ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
    \lipsum[1-3]\footnotemark
    \lipsum[1-3]\footnotemark
    \lipsum[1-3]\footnotemark
\end{mdframed}

\footnotetext{Note \#1}
\footnotetext{Note \#2}
\footnotetext{Note \#3}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!